# How to create DatePicker in php yii2 with jquery

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii2, jquery-ui-datepicker

My code is as below

```
<?php echo $form->field($model_emp_info, 'varDob')->textInput(['id'=>'datepicker'])?> 

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you included jquery-UI js and jquery-UI css file?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar or bootstrap css/js. this one is better for yii2 I think

Answer (score 2):

No need to manually attach it like that.

Yii2 has official extension for jQuery UI which is available [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui).

Add it through composer and then you can use widgets for jQuery UI components.

Basic example with DatePicker (using with model):

```
echo DatePicker::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'from_date',
    //'language' => 'ru',
    //'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
]);
```

You can read more in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html).